# Get OData or Atom Service feed for SSRS 2008 R2 Shared Dataset

Tags: dataset, ssrs-2008, odata, powerpivot

Is there anyway to get a shared dataset to simply dump it's contents in an Atom or OData feed that can then be consumed somewhere else?  In our scenario we want to build just the datasets and let users consume them from PowerPivot or elsewhere.

Thanks,
Brent

Answer (score 1):

You might find this useful:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240754.aspx

Comment: I know I can get the feeds from a report.  I was curious as to whether or not there is a way to run just the dataset to get the data.  It appears there is not.

Comment: I was just looking for this also see: http://www.odata.org/producers "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Reporting Services can expose data from reports as OData."

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like SSRS can easily consume OData sources but that they are considering it.

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/559570/ssrs-should-be-able-to-use-odata-as-a-data-source

In the following article Mattias suggests a workaround that might meet your needs by using the XML data source and embedding your OData query in the URL

http://mskold.blogspot.com/2011/05/tfs-odata-services-as-data-source.html

Comment: I don't want to consume OData from a report... I want to expose it from a shared data set.